# Ubuntu 22.04 RT Kernel Freezes on Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel

I am unable to boot into the real time kernel even in it recovery mode. Booting into the generic kernel works fine.

When booting in real time, the system hangs immediately on selecting it in grub. Choosing realtime under Advanced options shows a bit more and it hangs immediately after the “Loading initial ramdisk…” message.

I tried to boot into the generic kernel and check the previous boot log using journalctl -b-1 but it is not showing the actual previous boot attempt with the realtime kernel. Instead it is showing the last boot with the generic.

The system is a Dell Inspiron 24 All in one with NVIDIA graphics and a Core i5.

I’m at a loss on how to diagnose the issue. Would appreciate any help.